# How to make classes in xna - C#

Tags: c#, class, struct, xna

I have a problem with writing a class in XNA (and monogame). I made a class which solves animation problem, but whenever I compile it I get error like: `No graphics device manager found`. Tried to do the same thing in `struct`, but I get an error like: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in app.exe`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post the code you use.

Comment: we are not code wizards by that I mean we cannot possibly know what the heck it is you are talking about when we can't see the same code you're looking at.. come on now.. read the faq on how to ask a question and post all relevant code that pertains to your immediate issue(s)

Comment: I'll leave this question for the mind readers.

Comment: Even the _Infinite Number of Monkeys_ are not psychic.  Please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.NullReferenceException would be your exception for a null object meaning you have not "newed" an instance of one of your classes. Debugger should provide more detailed information.

No graphics device manager found. I'm not sure without seeing your code, but this probably means you left out graphics object reference entirely,forgot to initialize. Microsoft has a few examples on their official msdn.

When you reference it in Draw function like this:

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
```

It first has to be created like this:

```
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
```

And initialized like this:

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
```